# How to calculate correlation by using Z scores in python?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I have data in pandas data frame resembling following table:

```
  Z(A) Z(B) Z(TARGET)
1  0.4 0.17   0.96
2  0.2 0.37   0.45
3  0.1 -0.4   1.1
...
```

So, is it possible to calculate correlation of `A` and `B` with `TARGET`, by only using z-scores, preferably with pandas library?

I know that pandas library has method `corr` in its `DataFrame` class, and I saw other questions here talking about using that method. But data in those questions were original data (ie `A`, `B`, `TARGET`), while I have only z scores of those data (ie `Z(A)`, `Z(B)`, `Z(TARGET)`).
Can I apply `corr` function to my Z table as well, or do I need to calculate correlation of `A` with `TARGET` and `B` with `TARGET` using some other method?

I know that this question is more about math than about programming, so, sorry if I posted it in the wrong place. But it is kind of related to both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use corr here, at least not by itself. The Pearson correlation can be gotten from z-scores by this formula http://davidmlane.com/hyperstat/A51911.html. I would write a function to take the summation and then iterate through the data frame using a for loop and df.iloc[]. It will probably be fast enough, just not pretty.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this to me. I am new at statistical data analysis. Unfortunately, I do not have enough reputation to upvote your answer, so, I could not give you much reputation. But, in any case, thank you.